# How should I replace my naughty JSLint-shy function defs within loops?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, jslint

I'm getting a few `"Don't make functions within a loop."` errors from JSLint, anyone got any tidy suggestions on how to fix this stuff up?

Perhaps my naughtiness is excusable because of my YAHOO dependencies (`yd.` below)? I can safely say that the only time I've done the following:

```
for( var i=0; i<FLN.revealers.length;i++ )
{
    var revEl = FLN.revealers[i] ;
    var tag = yd.getElementsBy(function(el){
                return true;
            },'script',revEl );
}
```

... is when I need to perform an operation on a series of elements nested within a series of elements, to my mind this seems natural. I haven't found any slowness etc in my app, just curious because JSLint hurt my feelings :)

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927054/jslint-error-dont-make-functions-within-a-loop-leads-to-question-about-javasc

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll close this when poss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that in this case the function you're using does not need to be different for each iteration, so you can improve efficiency by using a single function instead:

```
var f = function(el) {
    return true;
};

for( var i=0; i<FLN.revealers.length;i++ )
{
    var revEl = FLN.revealers[i] ;
    var tag = yd.getElementsBy(f, 'script', revEl);
}
```