# Why won't passing `''.trim()` straight to `[].map()`'s callback work?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings. I want to trim each string in the array.

I thought using [`[].map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`''.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) would work...

```
[' a', ' b   ', 'c'].map(String.prototype.trim);
```

...but my console said...

> TypeError: String.prototype.trim called on null or undefined

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ne29s/).

I can't see any `null` or `undefined` values in my array.

`String.prototype.trim()` and `Array.prototype.map()` are defined in Chrome 17, which I'm using to test.

Why doesn't this work? I get the feeling I have overlooked something obvious.

I realise I could loop or drop a function in there. That's not the point of this question, however.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`trim` is on the `String` prototype, meaning that it expects the `this` context to be that of a string where as the `map` method on `Array` provides the current array item as the first argument and the `this` context being the global object.

Comment: Exactly! I knew it would be something obvious. My brain isn't working today. Thanks Slace.

Comment: So why does this not work? `[' a', ' b   ', 'c'].map(String.prototype.trim.apply);` ... and why does this work outside the `map()` context? `String.prototype.trim(' a ')` (note that it doesn't actually *work* - returns an empty string - but it doesn't throw an error either.)

Comment: @nrabinowitz: `apply`'s `this` doesn't get bound to `String.prototype.trim` - it gets bound to `undefined` or `null` or `window`. (This is why they invented `Function.bind()`.)

Comment: I was a bit slow with getting Ryan's comment at first, but I found [this](https://nemisj.com/some-interesting-aspects-of-call-method-in-javascript/) helpful.

Answer (score 35):

What @Slace says is the right explanation. <strike>@ThomasEding's answer also works but has one terrible inefficieny that it *may* create functions within a loop, which is [not a good thing to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927054/jslint-error-dont-make-functions-within-a-loop-leads-to-question-about-javas).</strike>

Another way of doing would be [(reference here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
[' a', ' b   ', 'c'].map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim);  
// gives ["a", "b", "c"]
```

**Standard browser disclaimer**: This will work wherever `Function.prototype.call` and `String.prototype.trim` will work and for older browsers, you can easily substitute `trim` with a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) like this:

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {  
  String.prototype.trim = function () {  
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');  
  };  
}
```

Update: Interstingly, while this works fastest in Chrome, @ThomasEding's method runs slightly faster in IE10 and FF20 - http://jsperf.com/native-trim-vs-regex-trim-vs-mixed

Comment: I'm pretty sure that @ThomasEdig's answer does not create more than one function. I'm assuming the `map` function accepts a function reference and then *calls it* once per iteration. The function itself is created once and then *passed to* the `map` function--just like jQuery's implementation of `map`: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.map

Comment: Yeah... From my tests, that appears to be true. I'll do the corrections.

Answer (score 25):

That's because `trim` is not being called with the proper `this` context. Remember that `this` is dynamically bound in JS. You will have to create a wrapper to pass to `trim` to properly bind `this`:

```
[' a', ' b   ', 'c'].map(function (str) {
  return str.trim();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think I've been using jQuery's `$.trim()` too often.

Comment: This is almost perfect except for the fact that you're creating functions in a loop.

Comment: @Mrchief: The above code does not do that. It would if you took my existing code and tossed it within a loop...

Comment: You're already in a loop when you're iterating thru the array. :) How do you think map is implemented? http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19

Comment: @Mrchief: That is one way to implement map. Another is via recursion. In either case, how map is implemented is moot. The function is created only once in this case. Then a pointer to the function is passed into map, and map uses the same reference as it does its work.

Comment: Good point! Not sure about the last part though. Its upto the browser how it optimizes.

Answer (score 3):

With ES6 syntax it can be as easy as this:

```
[' hello  ', '  world'].map(str => str.trim());
```

Comment: This is the best way of doing it in 2017. Let's see what happens in 2018 :D