# Why doesn't ["A","B","C"].map(String.prototype.toLowerCase.call) work?

Tags: javascript

This, of course, returns what you would expect:

```
["A","B","C"].map(function (x) {
    return x.toLowerCase();
});
// --> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

So does using String.prototype.toLowerCase.call:

```
["A","B","C"].map(function (x) {
    return String.prototype.toLowerCase.call(x);
});
// --> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

It also works if you pass the extra arguments given by map, as it throws away the arguments:

```
["A","B","C"].map(function (x, index, arr) {
    return String.prototype.toLowerCase.call(x, index, arr);
});
// --> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

But, this does not work:

```
["A","B","C"].map(String.prototype.toLowerCase.call);
// --> TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The following doesn't work either, because `arguments` has the Object prototype instead of the Array prototype, so `slice` is undefined on it.  Is the reason for the above behavior perhaps because of something like this-- where `slice` or some other similar Array function is used internally?

```
["A","B","C"].map(function (x) {
    return String.prototype.toLowerCase.apply(x, arguments.slice(1));
});
// --> TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: You're passing the `call` function to `map`, it's identical to `['A','B','C'].map(Function.prototype.call)`, you want to pass the `String.prototype.toLowerCase` function in a way that it is called on each element of the array.

Comment: The proper way to do this is the first example in your code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a special behavior of JavaScript's dot-notation.

`toLowerCase.call(x)` is working because JavaScript uses `toLowerCase` as `this` while executing `call`. This is how `call` (which is the same `Function.prototype.call` you find on every function) knows you want it to execute `toLowerCase`.

Passing `call` into another function loses that reference, so `this` no longer refers to `toLowerCase`.

Comment: The JavaScript engine executes `call` and within `call` it executes the `this` value, which happens to be `toLowerCase` in the correct code. What you have said and what I have said are facts consistent with each other.

Comment: This doesn't really explain the behaviour! Trick question, why does `[1,2,3].map(Math.sqrt)` work, but not `["A","B","C"].map(String.toLowerCase)` ?

Comment: `Math.sqrt` can be separated from `Math` safely due what is essentially an implementation detail you need to memorize before it can be trusted. `Math.sqrt` does not use its `this` value, which is only typically `Math`.

Comment: Ahh, I see!  It didn't occur to me that there is only a single `call()` in Javascript, and that `this` is used by it to get the function in front of it just like the rest of the language works.

Comment: @Cory - Now you are on to something, it's how `String`'s methods work that make them unsuitable to pass directly to methods like `map()`, and why the first example in the OP's question should generally be used, and why `Math`'s methods can safely be passed

Answer (score 27):

Similar Question: [Why won't passing `''.trim()` straight to `[].map()`'s callback work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304007/why-wont-passing-trim-straight-to-maps-callback-work?rq=1)

Map has a optional thisArg which can be used like so:

```
['A', 'B', 'C'].map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.toLowerCase);  
// gives ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that `String.prototype.toLowerCase.call == Function.prototype.call`. If you want to get a function that converts the argument to lower case, you could bind the `toLowerCase` function to the `call` function like that:

```
var toLowerCase = String.prototype.toLowerCase.call.bind(String.prototype.toLowerCase);
["A","B","C"].map(toLowerCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

> But, this does not work:
>
> ["A","B","C"].map(String.prototype.toLowerCase.call);

The first argument passed to [*map*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19) is supposed to be a function that will be passed the value of members of the array. The above passes a direct reference to *Function.prototype.call*, so the function will attempt:

```
call(x);
```

So *call* has been passed without setting its *this*, so it will be *undefined* on entering the call function.