# Using apply or call to create a pointfree function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, apply, method-call, pointfree

Let's say that I want to create a function that trims its input, one way I can do it is simply

```
x => x.trim()
```

Another way would be

```
x => String.prototype.trim.call(x)
```

Which has the advantage that if `x` has defined an override for the `.trim()`, I can still grab the implementation from the prototype. By extension, if I want to use the same things in a `.map()` I can do either,

```
[" foo", "bar "].map(x => x.trim())
[" foo", "bar "].map(x => String.prototype.trim.call(x));
```

I wante do make a [pointfree function](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) though. What I don't understand is why can't use a uninvoked function created with [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
[" foo", "bar "].map(String.prototype.trim.call);
```

I also tried [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) which because there are no arguments is effectively the same thing.

Likewise, outside of a map you also can't use the function `.call` function

```
> fn = String.prototype.trim.call
[Function: call]
> fn('asdf')
TypeError: fn is not a function
```

So my questions are,

1. In the above, the function returned by `String.prototype.trim.call` does what exactly? What kind of function is that?
2. Why doesn't my attempt with `.call` work?
3. Is there anyway to do this with `.bind`, `.apply`, or `.call`?

Comment: `map` passes additional arguments. It passes the item, the index of that item and the array.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304007/why-wont-passing-trim-straight-to-maps-callback-work

Comment: I know that the JS community tends to rely on reference identity but still you might want to consider `invoke = (name, ...args) => o => o[name] (...args)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't passing \`''.trim()\` straight to \`\[\].map()\`'s callback work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304007/why-wont-passing-trim-straight-to-maps-callback-work)

Comment: this has nothing to do with trim.. that's just an example.

Answer (score 2):

> What I don't understand is why can't use a uninvoked function created with [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
>
> ```
> [" foo", "bar "].map(String.prototype.trim.call);
> ```

The problem here is that all functions inherit the same single `call` method from `Function.prototype`; so the above is equivalent to

```
[" foo", "bar "].map(Function.prototype.call);
```

For your code to work, `call` would need to "remember" that you got it from `String.prototype.trim` and not from some other function; but that's simply not how method calls work in JavaScript. In a method-call expression like `foo.bar()`, `foo` isn't just the object whose `bar` property gets invoked as a function, it's also the object that gets implicitly passed as `this` *to* that function. In the case of `String.prototype.trim.call(x)`, the only reason `call` knows to invoke `String.prototype.trim` is that you're using method-call syntax, so it can get it from `this`.

---

> 1. In the above, the function returned by `String.prototype.trim.call` does what exactly? What kind of function is that?

It's a method that takes an object and zero or more arguments, and that, when called on a function, invokes that function as a method on that object, passing those arguments.

> 2. Why doesn't my attempt with `.call` work?

Because it tries to invoke `call` as a free function instead of as a method; so `call` doesn't receive a `this` argument telling it what function to invoke, so it can't do its job. (It will most likely receive the "default object", e.g. `window`, as its `this` argument; but there are some subtleties that I'm not sure of. You can try `[" foo", "bar "].map(function () { return this; })` in your testbed to see what it gives you in your environment.)

> 3. Is there anyway to do this with `.bind`, `.apply`, or `.call`?

Yes; you can write:

```
[" foo", "bar "].map(Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.trim))
```

where `Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.trim)` is a function that, when called, invokes `call` on `String.prototype.trim`. (In other words, `bind` handles "remembering" that `String.prototype.trim` is the object that you want to pass as `this`.)

That said, I really think your original version,

```
[" foo", "bar "].map(x => x.trim())
```

is vastly superior. If someone has overridden `trim()`, you should trust that it was for a good reason, and that you should indeed call that override instead of forcing the use of the inherited one instead.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! It boils down to the signature of [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax):

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

The key to understanding the behavior you noticed is the optional `thisArg` - it's the context that will be supplied to the callback

Furthermore, [from the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description):

> If a thisArg parameter is provided to map, it will be used as callback's this value. Otherwise, the value undefined will be used as its this value.

So that meand that `undefined` will be used as the context for the callback, which in this case is `String.prototype.trim.call`

Here's where it gets interesting... the normal context for `Function.prototype.call` (which `String.prototype.trim.call` inherits) is the function that it calls, i.e. `String.prototype.trim` in this case. The first argument to `Function.prototype.call` provides the context to the function that will be called.

In the case of `<< Array >>.map(String.prototype.trim.call)`, the context provided to `String.prototype.trim.call` is `undefined`, which means we wind up attempting to call `undefined` with a context of an element from the array. All clear? It's definitely a bit of a mind twist.

We can take advantage of this behavior to achieve the effect we desire by providing `String.prototype.trim` as `thisArg` in `<< Array >>.map(callback, thisArg)` and using `Function.call` as the callback:

```js
console.log([" foo", "bar "].map(Function.call, String.prototype.trim));
```

Another way to think of it is that `String.prototype.trim` provides the context to `Function.call` to produce a bound function, and then each element of the array provides the context to the bound function.