# How to pass parameters to external function through map.event.addListener

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add listeners to google map events, but <strike>not using anonymous functions but named, external functions</strike> as this happens inside a loop, I do not want to define an anonymous function right there, but instead use a named, external function:

**Not:**

```
for (...) {
    googleMap.event.addListener(instance, eventName, function() {...});
}
```

**But rather sth. like:**

```
doSomething = function(parameter1, parameter2...) {
    ...
}

for (...) {
    googleMap.event.addListener(instance, eventName, params, doSomething);
}
```

When "instance" is a google map marker, I can add the parameter(s) to the marker using `marker.set(paramName, paramValue)` and then access the parameters inside the event handler function via `this.paramName`, but is there any other way to pass values to the event handler function when I don't want to use an anonymous one?

Any advice welcome, Roman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem.  Here is a solution.  It genuinely avoids the create function in a loop problem, by using the pattern described here

[In JavaScript, what are specific reasons why creating functions within a loop can be computationally wasteful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834740/in-javascript-what-are-specific-reasons-why-creating-functions-within-a-loop-ca)

Which I call the "function factory" pattern.

The other ingredients are that inside the function "this" refers to the object which raised the function (the thing on the map which was clicked, or whatever), and because JavaScript is completely dynamic, you can attach additional properties at will to the thing which was clicked, and query them by calling this.blah inside the function

```
function doSomethingHandlerFactory(){
var f = function(event){
    //do something, for example call a method on a property we attached to the object which raised the event
    this.blah.clicked(event);
};
return f;
}

//add a property to the google overlay object (for example a polyline which we've already set up)
thePolyline.blah = ...;

//get a handle for a function, attach the event (in this case to a polyline), and keep  
//a reference to the event (in case we want to call removeListener later).  The latter
//is optional.
var f = doSomethingHandlerFactory();
var ev = google.maps.event.addListener(thePolyline, 'click', f);
```

I hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping your named function in an anonymous function:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(instance, eventName, function() { doSomething(parameter1, parameter2,...) });
```

Comment: Not bad, geocodezip. That way I could pass my parameter and still use a named function. But to be honest, the idea was not to define a function at this place, since the addListener happens in a loop and I think it is bad style to define a function within a loop... I will add this to the original question - sorry, should've mentioned this earlier.