# Creating a custom google map with multiple markers and popup windows - Issues

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary

Been trying to create a custom google map, i've written the code but something isn't quite right, wondered if anyone could point out what I've done wrong. Code is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(30,0);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 2,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  var countries = Array();

  countries.push({
      marker: new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(4.52,115), map: map, title: 'Test'}),
      infowindow: new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "Hello world"})
  });
  countries.push({
      marker: new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.45,23.20), map: map, title: 'Test2'}),
      infowindow: new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "Hello world2"})
  });
  countries.push({
      marker: new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(12.15,-1.30), map: map, title: 'Test3'}),
      infowindow: new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "Hello world3"})
  });

  for each (var item in countries) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(item.marker, 'click', function() {
        item.infowindow.open(map, item.marker);
      });

}
```

Comment: _You_ need to tell _us_ what isn't right.

Comment: The map is refusing to load, i just get an area of white space where the map should be

Comment: [Don't use `for each` to iterate over an `Array`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description) Use a regular `for` loop.

Comment: thanks but for doesn't seem to allow the info windows to appear, for each does…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from [using the wrong style `for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description), you're trying to [make a function in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037598/how-to-get-around-the-jslint-error-dont-make-functions-within-a-loop). **This is a very common mistake.** Since JS has function-level scoping, not block level, this doesn't work as you might expect.

Try this:

```
function makeCallback(country) {
    return function () {
        country.infowindow.open(map, country.marker);
    };
}

var item;
for (var i=0; i<countries.length; i++) {
    item = countries[i];
    google.maps.event.addListener(item.marker, 'click', makeCallback(item));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, all sorted now :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine, I see a map with 3 markers but without knowing what the problem is it's hard to tell.

A few guesses:

- You're missing a curly brace at the end which closes initialize
- Do you have a div with an id of "map_canvas"?
- Is initialize being called from anywhere?
- Have you included the Google maps javascript?

Comment: The issue was that the map wasn't displaying, strange that it works for you, will retest, thanks!

Comment: hmm still doesn't want to work for me, I have a curly bracket at the end, i have <body onload="initialize()"> a div with the correct id (the div is being displayed but it's fully white with no map in) and I have included the js (<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&region=GB"></script>), any more ideas? thanks!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Jn74kdme here's a very rough mockup that should work? As a side note Matt, above, is right about using a regular for loop.

Comment: That's where Matt's comment comes in: change to use a regular for loop. e.g. for (var i=0;i<countries.length;i++) {

Comment: @ambuletz instead of pastebin try http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com for HTML/CSS/JS.