# Don't make functions within a loop

Tags: javascript, jslint

What would be the correct way to solve the jslint error in this case? I'm adding a getter function to an object which uses this. I don't know how to do this without creating the function inside the loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i<processorList.length; ++i) {
   result[i] = {
       processor_: timestampsToDateTime(processorList[i]),
       name_: processorList[i].processorName,
       getLabel: function() { // TODO solve function in loop.
            return this.name_;
       }
   };
}
```

Comment: Why not silence the jslint error altogether? [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40060701/307454) how.

Comment: Because the error is there for a reason. I don't think its very nice to write code like this where numerous of the exact same functions get created for no real reason.

Comment: _Sometimes_ jslint is not necessarily the ultimate guide to proper coding style...

Comment: True (I think, I haven't used jslint for years), but any code that creates a lot of the same resources with no real reason is bad code in my book. The only situation in which that would be ok is if it results in performance gains. In this case you could argue that it makes the code a little more readable, but I believe that's very marginal. As a javascript developer you need to understand how `this` works.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Move the function outside the loop:

```
function dummy() {
    return this.name_;
}
// Or: var dummy = function() {return this.name;};
for (var i = 0; i<processorList.length; ++i) {
   result[i] = {
       processor_: timestampsToDateTime(processorList[i]),
       name_: processorList[i].processorName,
       getLabel: dummy
   };
}
```

... Or just ignore the message by using the [`loopfunc` option](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#loopfunc) at the top of the file:

```
/*jshint loopfunc:true */
```

Comment: Ah I didn't think the "this" pointer would still work in that way. Isn't it pointing to the dummy function instead of the object at result[i]? In other words is name_ still correctly found?

Comment: @0x80 `this` points to the function's context, which is `results[i]` in this case. http://jsfiddle.net/W5vfw/

Comment: @RobW: May I know, what makes the difference by just calling a named function in the loop?

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni When the function expression is put inside the loop, it is constructed on each iteration. Moving the function expression/declaration outside the loop has some performance benefits: http://jsperf.com/closure-vs-name-function-in-a-loop/2

Comment: What happens when you want to pass some parameters to the function?

Comment: @Levani Then you usually need a [closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Comment: What if, in this example, the dummy function itself was creating a function? Should that function be declared outside the dummy function? @RobW

Comment: @ErikAGriffin It depends. It is a trade-off between performance and readability (and you should usually favor readability). See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779752/javascript-nested-function-performance for some arguments for and against nesting functions.

Comment: @RobW The code for the jshint option contains an erroneous space (at least in the version that I'm using). It should be `/*jshint loopfunc:true */` (no space before the j), and it should be at the top of the file