# How to solve the jshint error `Don't make functions within a loop.` with jquery $.grep

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jshint

The following javascript code gives me the *Don't make functions within a loop.* error

```
/* Get the favorite products from the data using the id */
productDataCategory[FAVORITES].length = 0/* empty favorites productDataCategory */;
for ( i = 0; i < currentUser.favorites.length; i++) {
    product = $.grep(productData, function(e){ return e.id === currentUser.favorites[i]; })[0];
    productDataCategory[FAVORITES].push(p);
}
```

I've looked the question up and saw some similar questions asked by other members
[How to get around the jslint error 'Don't make functions within a loop.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037598/how-to-get-around-the-jslint-error-dont-make-functions-within-a-loop)
[Don't make functions within a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320343/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop)

The problem I have is that I'm using a $.grep function inside the loop to find the product in an array.
I dont know how to resolve this issue with the answers in the above questions.

---

Data from a logged user

```
{
    "user": "MBO",
    "email": "my@mail.com",
    "username": "Marcel",
    "photoURL": "url_here",
    "favorites": [13,25,40,56]
}
```

Comment: Why don't use just a single `.grep` (instead of looping several of them), but check for `$.inArray(e.id, currentUser.favorites) !== -1` instead? Do you need the result array to be re-ordered by `currentUser.favorites` order?

Comment: Thats a really good question. Answer is that i never heard of $.inArray. That will make things quite faster! Using .grep for each product takes a lot of time! (I'll get into that)

Comment: @raina77ow `.inArray` only gives locations. Does it handles multiple locations at once? (put in a whole array and get all the locations). If it doesn't, than it means I need to `.inArray` every product + get the data with the given location. `.grep` seems to be a better solution for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the function outside the loop:

```
/* Get the favorite products from the data using the id */
productDataCategory[FAVORITES].length = 0/* empty favorites productDataCategory */;
var f = function(e){ return e.id === currentUser.favorites[i]; };
for ( i = 0; i < currentUser.favorites.length; i++) {
  product = $.grep(productData, f)[0];
  productDataCategory[FAVORITES].push(p);
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.
(btw i saw that you edited your answer! both are working, and the current is very neat)