# JavaScript loop an array - ReferenceError | i is not defined

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, automated-tests, postman

newbie at JavaScript and Postman here.

I have set up a basic test in postman using JS to compare names in a web response to names in a data file. The array of names is in an external data csv file.

I want to loop through the array, but I get an error:

```
"ReferenceError | i is not defined"
```

Code:

```js
var newResponse = responseBody;

let nameArray = data.name;

for (let i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(nameArray.length);
}

pm.test("Web vs. Data: Person", function() {
  pm.expect(newResponse.Item[i].name).to.equal(nameArray.Item[i].person);
});

console.log(newResponse.Item[i].name);
console.log(nameArray.Item[i].person);
```

Comment: Could you not use `pm.iterationData.get('name')` to get the value from the data file, I don't really understand why your looping through that in the why you are?

Answer (score 1):

Your end scope "}" character missing please change with this code;

```
var newResponse = responseBody;

let nameArray = data.name;

for (let i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {

    console.log(nameArray.length);

    pm.test("Web vs. Data: Person", function () {
        pm.expect(newResponse.Item[i].name).to.equal(nameArray.Item[i].person);

    });

    console.log(newResponse.Item[i].name);
    console.log(nameArray.Item[i].person);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`let` is block scoped so it will cause **ReferenceError** out of the `for` loop. The variable `i` will not be referred outside of the `for` loop. So you've to move your codeblock inside the `for` loop like below. Hope this helps :)

```
var newResponse = responseBody;
let nameArray = data.name;

for(let i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++){
  console.log(nameArray.length);
  pm.test("Web vs. Data: Person" ,function(){
  pm.expect(newResponse.Item[i].name).to.equal(nameArray.Item[i].person);
  });

  console.log (newResponse.Item[i].name);
  console.log(nameArray.Item[i].person); 
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I now get an error 'don't make functions within a loop'. Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: @Bill_Martin take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320343/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop this will help you, need to move function outside of the loop and call it from the loop with incremented value of `i`