# How do I move the function outside the loop

Tags: javascript

I've an warning that "Don't make functions within a loop", I know there are already some post regarding this [Don't make functions within a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320343/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop)

But I'm newbie and has no idea how to do this, can anyone help?

```
for (const el of testing) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const apple = this.dataset.open;
    document.getElementById(apple).classList.add(orange);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in fact when you do

```
for (const el of testing) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const apple = this.dataset.open;
    document.getElementById(apple).classList.add(orange);
  });
}
```

you create a new instance of a new function each time the loop is iterate

a better way is to have a function declared outside the loop

```
function myfunction() {
    const apple = this.dataset.open;
    document.getElementById(apple).classList.add(orange);
  });

for (const el of testing) {
  el.addEventListener("click", myfunction);
}
```