# How do I return the number of rows of a table according to a search criteria in Web SQL?

Tags: html, web-sql

I have created a database called todo with table name todo having fields like title,date etc.  The table is empty right now.

I have defined a function which takes title as parameter and check whether table contains that title or not.

It should return the number of rows.

GetTitle function:

```
todo.webdb.GetTitle = function(title) {
    var db = todo.webdb.db;
    db.transaction(function(tx){
      tx.executeSql("SELECT title FROM todo WHERE title=?", [title],
          loadTitle,
          todo.webdb.onError);
      });
  }
```

loadTitle Function:

```
function loadTitle(tx, rs) {
    return rs.rows.length;
  }
```

GetTitle Function is called:

```
row=todo.webdb.GetTitle("Hello");
alert(row);
```

I get alert `'undefined'` it should return `0`

I am confused right now how to resolve this issue.

Comment: What browser are you using. You could be using a browser will no support for web database. Try using Taffy.js instead. You get better browser support and they have a function called `count` to get the size of a selection.

Comment: thanks larry for replying i am using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the transactions are asynchronous, so you need to callback function to receive the value.

```
todo.webdb.GetTitle = function(title, callback) {
    var db = todo.webdb.db;
    db.transaction(function(tx){
          tx.executeSql("SELECT title FROM todo WHERE title=?", [title],
              (function loadTitle(tx, rs){
                    callback( rs.rows.length );
              }),
              todo.webdb.onError);
      });
} 
todo.webdb.GetTitle( "Hello", function(count){
    alert( "count = " + count );
});
```

Here's an excellent tutorial for more information.

http://blog.darkcrimson.com/2010/05/local-databases/

### Update

Don't make functions inside a loop for this main reason.

Both `i` and `title` are referencing a value created out of local scope.
So the last value of assigned to both `i` and `title` will be displayed.

```
for (i = 0; i < itemcount; i++) {
    alert('i outside if:' + i);
    var title = x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    
    todo.webdb.GetTitle( title, function (count) {
        if (!count) {
            alert('i inside if:' + i);
            alert( title ); 
        }
    });
}
```

Fix:
Generate a function that has the values locked in a closure.

```
var createTitleCallBack = function( i, title ){
    return function (count) {
        if (!count) {
            alert('i inside if:' + i);
            alert( title ); 
        }
    };
};
for (i = 0; i < itemcount; i++) {
    alert('i outside if:' + i);
    var title = x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    
    todo.webdb.GetTitle( title, createTitleCallBack( i, title ) );
}
```

Comment: I have modified the code according to your suggestion but i am getting undefined alert message when i tried to alert result inside the function and alert the row after the row=todo.webdb.GetTitle("Hello");

Comment: thanks larry for your suggestion its working now but i am having some issue can you help me out.

Comment: Update your question if it's not too big of a change from the original.

Comment: larry i have updated my question (marked in black). please have a look at it.

Comment: @PankajKhurana Possible duplicate for your updated question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037598/how-to-get-around-the-jslint-error-dont-make-functions-within-a-loop