# event handler that knows the event name

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, scope

I have a socket.io server that generates many events, and I want to catch all of them and print a similar message. Right now, I do this:

```
for (var event in {eventA: 1, eventB: 1, eventC: 1}) {
    this.translationSocket.on(event, function(result) {
        console.log("Server sent an event of type "+event);
    });
}
```

When the server sends eventA, eventB and eventC, I see this:

```
Server sent an event of type eventC
Server sent an event of type eventC
Server sent an event of type eventC
```

i.e. my program catches all events, but always displays the type of eventC...

I tried the following variations:

- remove the "var" before the "event" inside the "for": "for (event ..."
- adding a statement 'var msg = "Server sent an event of type "+event;' either before the 'on' statement or just before the 'console.log' statement, and then 'console.log(msg)'.

None of these variations worked...

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with socket.io or node.js, this is well known JavaScript "quirk". The value of `event` is evaluated when the code is executed, which is when the loop is finished. You need to wrap thing into a function call to preserve the value.

```
var listen = function(socket, event) {
    socket.on(event, function(result) {
        console.log("Server sent an event of type "+event);
    });
}


for (var event in {eventA: 1, eventB: 1, eventC: 1}) {
    listen(event);
}
```

Or (shorter version):

```
for (var event in {eventA: 1, eventB: 1, eventC: 1}) {
    (function(event) {
        this.translationSocket.on(event, function(result) {
            console.log("Server sent an event of type "+event);
        });
    })(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `for (var event in ...)` you're declaring a variable and because of the variable scope rules in **JavaScript** it will be valid outside of the foreach loop.

The `event` variable becomes `eventC` at the end of the loop.
So it's value, when you want to print it will be `eventC`.

You can do something like this:

```
function generateCallback(e, result) {
    return function () {
        console.log("Server sent an event of type " + e);
    };
}

var e;
// ...
for (e in {eventA: 1, eventB: 1, eventC: 1}) {
    this.translationSocket.on(e, generateCallback(e, result));
}
```

To prevent confusion [you'd better not to declare variables in for statements](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/pull/29#issuecomment-831460).

And also it's better, [not to make functions within a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3037598/303270). That's why I used `generateCallback` instead of making a callback function within the loop.

Comment: Thanks, this "var" issue is really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `socket.io-events` on npm.  You can capture *all* events and handle them however you want without having to bind separate handlers.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
var router = require('socket.io-events')();
 router.on('*', function (sock, args, next) {
 var name = args.shift(), msg = args.shift();
 sock.emit('received event', name, msg);
});
io.use(router);
```