# D3 onClick handler seems to have wrong scope when executed

Tags: javascript, d3.js, functional-programming, closures

I have the following javascript code for D3, which behaves strange in my opinion. As I'm new to D3 I might be missing something, but I have no idea at all. The problem is marked by the alert calls:

I loop over a set of data sets which are drawn as lines (stripped from the code) and as circles/dots on these lines. When I click on the circle, I want to execute some code in the onClick handler. The onClick handler is a closer defined per loop iteration which is passed to the D3 on() method. Quite normal javascript stuff so far. But:

The first alert always displays the correct value as I would expect it. I would the value of chartDataItem to be bound to the onClick closure, so it's supposed to have the same value when it's called. But if onClick is executed, I always get the value from the last iteration.

Is there something special with the D3 on() method that I don't see?

```
for(var i=0; i<chartData.length; i++){

    var chartDataItem = chartData[i];
    var currentData = chartDataItem["data"];

    alert(chartDataItem["name"]); // <- displays the correct value per iteration
    var onClick = function(d){
        alert(chartDataItem["name"]); // <- should bind chartDataItem to the scope of the closure?!
    }

    var dataLines = lineChart.dataLinesGroup.selectAll('.data-line color' + i)
            .data([currentData]);

    // Draw the lines
    ...

    // Draw the points
    lineChart.dataCirclesGroup = lineChart.svg.append('svg:g');

    var circles = lineChart.dataCirclesGroup.selectAll('.data-point color' + i)
        .data(currentData);

    circles
        .enter()
            .append('svg:circle')
                .attr('class', 'data-point color' + i)
                .style('opacity', 1e-6)
                ... more attr and style calls ...
                .on("click", onClick)
            .transition()
            .duration(0)
                .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d.title) })
                .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d.value) })
                .style('opacity', 1);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has to do with a for loops body not being a closure, so you are redefining stuff each time it loops, and it ends up using the definition of the variables in the last iteration of the loop.

Here's a fiddle on a simplified version of your problem that uses a forEach: http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/GxyK6/

```
var chartData = [{data: "one"}, {data: "two"}, {data: "three"}];
var body = d3.select("body");

chartData.forEach(function(d){
    var chartDataItem = d;

    var onClick = function(d){
        alert(chartDataItem.data);
    }

    var div = body.append("div");
    var words = div.selectAll("div").data([chartDataItem]);
    words.enter().append("div").text(function(d) { return d.data; } ).on("click", onClick);    
});
```

With a forEach, the body of the forEach is a closure, so the local scope of the closure is preserved.

Answer (score 3):

Creating javascript [functions in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037598/how-to-get-around-the-jslint-error-dont-make-functions-within-a-loop) is a little tricky; on every iteration of the loop `chartDataItem` is redefined. Since each onClick function looks to `chartDataItem` to see what to text to alert, the last value of `chartDataItem` will be alerted each time. You can verify this by running

```
chartDataItem = 'test alert'
```

in the console after your loop has run, then clicking on any of the circles.

To get around this, you can use a closure to prevent each function's alert text from being modified:

```
var onClick = function(alertText){
  return function(){ alert(alertText); };
}(chartDataItem['name']);
```

Alternatively, using [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of a for loop avoids this problem by executing each cycle of the loop in its own function.

An even better solution: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/