# How can I loop through a list of form ID's and add a submit handler to each?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website containing a lot of different contact forms. I want to keep an array of their ID's (and other related settings) so I can loop through them and add submit handlers to each one.

The problem is that only the last form in the array seems to get a handler attached to it.

List of forms:

```
forms = [
    {id: '#contact-form-1', ...},
    {id: '#contact-form-2', ...}
]
```

How I'm trying to add submit handlers:

```
for (i in forms) {
    $(document).on('submit', forms[i].id, function(){
        // Validation, send email etc.
    }
}
```

Is $(document).on() the right way to approach this? I have tried $(forms[i].id).submit(); but I get the same outcome; only the last form in the list gets bound to.

Comment: The problem is that all the handlers share the same variable "i". The event handler will be invoked such that `this` refers to the form instance when the handler is called, so you probably don't need to use "i" in the handlers anyway.

Comment: In fact you may be able to do what you need with just one blanket handler that works for all forms on the page.

Comment: Are you binding the same function to *all* of them? Because if you are you're making this needlessly-complex and could use `$('form[id^="contact-form-"]')` or simply switch to a class-name: `$('form.contact-form')`.

Comment: There's different UI things associated with each one otherwise I would have definitely done it this way. Much easier than maintaining a list of forms!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to do this the other way round.

```
/* listen for ALL submit forms */
$('form').on('submit', function() {

  /* get the id of the this one */
   var _id = $(this).attr('id');

    /* do some conditions on _ID */


));
```

So say your objects was like :

```
var formIDs = {
      formidOne: { func : function() { alert('called form id one'); }},
      formidTwo: { func : function() { alert('called form id two'); }}
    };
```

Then could do say:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {

  /* get the id of the this one */
   var _id = $(this).attr('id');

    /* call the form function associated with this form id */
    formIDs[_id].func();

));
```

---

A few ways to do this, all depends how you want to organise your code , this would be a little easier as only defining the listener once

---

**Adding an edit** : as not really explained what is going wrong in your original code - which is that the context of `i` is not retained correctly ( already hinted in a comment )

The solution is to make use of another function :

```
function makeHandler (index) {
 $('#'+forms[index].id).on('submit', function(){... });
}

for (i in forms) {  makeHandler(i); }
```

This is the best place to look up problems around making functions in a loop -  [How to fix jslint error 'Don't make functions within a loop.'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037598/how-to-get-around-the-jslint-error-dont-make-functions-within-a-loop)

---

Would still favour using **one** handler as above, easier to maintain / read ( imo )

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from within a closure like `$.each`.

```
$.each(forms, function(index, item){
   $(document).on('submit', forms[index].id, function(){.....

})
```

Without jQuery can create closure of `for` loop index doing:

```
for (i in forms) {

    (function(i){
       /* your code here */
     })(i);
}
```

Comment: `for in` should be [avoided for object traversal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) or the property checked with `hasOwnProperty()`..